# How can I simplify this select function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't know anything about javascript. I just found this snippet in the web when I was trying to find a solution on how to achieve what I need. Is there any way to simplify this since I will be adding around 40 elements that I need to show and hide.

```
var $selects = $('.filters select');
  $selects.on('change', getValues).first().trigger("change");
  function getValues() {
    var vals = $selects.map(function() {
        return this.value;
    }).get();
    if (vals.join('') === "a1b2c3") {
        $(".box_wrapper").not(".a1b2c3").hide();
        $(".a1b2c3").show();
        $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(".a1b2c3").offset().top},
        'slow');
    }
    else if (vals.join('') === "d4e5f6") {
        $(".box_wrapper").not(".d4e5f6").hide();
        $(".d4e5f6").show();
        $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(".d4e5f6").offset().top},
        'slow');
    }
    else{
        $(".vid_box").hide();
    }
}
```

I think I can simplify this further by getting the joined value from the select boxes and use it on the function above and since I am using the same value combination for the class. I just don't know how. Is that possible? Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: does this code work?

Comment: How about using a switch/case?

Comment: can you show us your html

Comment: Oh, I missed that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my final code. Thanks @MJH for all the help.

```
  var $selects = $('.filters select');
  $selects.on('change', getValues).first().trigger("change");
  function getValues() {
  var $selects = $('.filters select');
  $selects.on('change', getValues).first().trigger("change");
  function getValues() {
    var vals = $selects.map(function() {
        return this.value;
    }).get();
    var vwarp = vals.join('');
    if (vwarp == vwarp) {
        $(".box_wrapper").not("." + vwarp).hide();
        $("." + vwarp).show();
        $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("." + vwarp).offset().top},
        'slow');
    }
    else{
        $(".box_wrapper").hide();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this (air code):

```
var $selects = $('.filters select');
$selects.on('change', getValues).first().trigger("change");
function getValues() {
    var vals = $selects.map(function() {
        return this.value;
    }).get();

    var values = [ "a1b2c3", "d4e5f6" ];

    var vj = vals.join('');

    if (values.indexOf(vj) !== -1) {
        $(".box_wrapper").not("." + vj).hide();
        $("." + vj)).show();
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("." + vj)).offset().top
        }, 'slow');
    }
    else {
        $(".vid_box").hide();
    }
}
```

Comment: Following your example, I manage to simplify it but I am having an 'Uncaught Type Error' in the scrolltop function if I use: `$('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("." + vj)).offset().top
        }, 'slow');`

I get no error though if I just use the normal class targeting.

Comment: Well, I did say it was air code. What do you get if you log `vj` to the console within the `if` block? Is it the same as the normal class value?

Comment: Not really sure how to do that. Can you tell me the exact command I should be typing on the browser console? Sorry.

Comment: No problem. Before the `$(".box_wrapper")` line, add this line: `console.log(vj);`. Then run the code, and inspect your browser's console to see what was output.

Comment: Thanks! I think I figured it out. It returns error since I don't have the element yet to go with the value for the script to scroll to.

Comment: Here's my final code:

    `var $selects = $('.filters select');
  $selects.on('change', getValues).first().trigger("change");
  function getValues() {
    var vals = $selects.map(function() {
        return this.value;
    }).get();
    var vwarp = vals.join('');
    if (vwarp == vwarp) {console.log(vwarp)
        $(".box_wrapper").not("." + vwarp).hide();
        $("." + vwarp).show();
    }
    else{
        $(".box_wrapper").hide();
    }
    
    $('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("." + vwarp).offset().top},
    'slow');
}`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest something like this.

```
var $selects = $('.filters select');

$selects.on('change', function() {

    var value = $selects.map(function() {
        return this.value;
    }).get();

    $(".box_wrapper").not("." + value).hide();
    $(".box_wrapper." + value).show();
    $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("." + value).offset().top},
    'slow');
});

$selects.first().trigger("change");
```